# Accessing parent Controllers scope within a directive that uses ControllerAs and scope:true

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to use ControllerAs in a directive with no $scope injection, using this instead, and I'm struggling when scope:true

When I use an isolated scope everything works fine because I can use `bindToController: true`, but in this case I'm missing something and I don´t know what.

I have this code. As you can see, I'm trying to print foo3 (from MyController) and foo4 (from MyDirectiveController) in my directive. This can be easily done using $scope injection in both controllers, but when I try to use this then I don´t know if I can (and how to) access foo3 from MyController in my directive.

```
angular
    .module("app",[])
    .controller('MyController', MyController)
    .controller('MyDirectiveController', MyController)
    .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

function MyController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.foo3 = 'foo3';
}

function myDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        controller: MyDirectiveController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        template: '{{vm.foo3}} - {{vm.foo4}}'
    }
}

function MyDirectiveController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.foo4 = 'foo4'; 
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danaya/9yhgjk4g/5/).

Comment: When you say, it doesn't work, what do you mean?

Comment: If instead of {{vm.foo2}} in my template I use {{vm.foo}} it doesn´t print anything. If I use $scope no problem, as the scope in the directive inherits from the scope in MyController, but when using this (vm in this case) I don´t know how to achieve the same.

Comment: See this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/9yhgjk4g/3/, it looks alright to me.

Comment: Sure, because you're using foo in both cases. I want to use foo, from MyController, instead of foo2, from the directive's controller.

Comment: Ahh got you.. My bad!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `controllerAs` syntax when you instantiate your MyController like so.

```
<!-- Notice the "as vmMy" syntax : Now everything can be accessed via "vmMy." -->

<div ng-controller="MyController as vmMy"> 
    <my-directive></my-directive> 
</div>
```

Now anytime you use `vmMy.` notation it'll access things from MyController's scope!

So your template can now be like so:

```
template: 'From MyController: {{vmMy.foo}}<br> From MyDirective: {{vm.foo2}}'
```

**[jsFiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/9yhgjk4g/2/)**

Comment: Ok, but is this the only way to do that? I mean, what if I want to use the same directive with different controllers and not only MyController? When I used $scope I didn´t need to do that.

Comment: You could pass things into the directive through attributes, such as `<my-directive something="vmMy.foo" />` where vmMy.foo could be totally different in other instances you could pass some other outside controller thing. Then you'd access the item within the directives `scope : { something : '@' }` object. @ meaning that something is an attribute.

Comment: There's a lot of different ways, but using the attribute way for example in your template it'd simply be used with `{{ vm.something }}` since it becomes part of `vm` within your directive that way. So it doesn't care what you pass into it

Comment: Ok, I just realized you actually answered my question with your first answer. The trick is that you used different values for the controller, vm and vmMy, whilst I was using the same and it didn´t work. Many thanks.