# Access parent property from directive controller with ControllerAs syntax and no $scope injection

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

This is a followed up question from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714062/accessing-parent-controllers-scope-within-a-directive-that-uses-controlleras-and/30714226?noredirect=1#comment49492884_30714226).

How can I access a property defined in MyController from MyDirectiveController to change its value or just read it and use it for something else? (commented line in the code).

```
angular
    .module("app",[])
    .controller('MyController', MyController)
    .controller('MyDirectiveController', MyController)
    .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

function MyController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.foo = 'fooController';
}

function myDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        controller: MyDirectiveController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        template: '{{vmMy.foo}} - {{vm.foo}}'
    }
}

function MyDirectiveController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.foo = 'fooDirective'; 

    // vmMyfoo = 'fooDirective';
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danaya/9yhgjk4g/7/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`bindToController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-bindtocontroller-) (available from v1.3.x) setting of directive to bind values to controller instance instead of scope object.

```
function myDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            value: '='
        },
        controller: MyDirectiveController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        template: '{{vm.value}} - {{vm.foo}}'
    }
}
```

and in HTML you pass value to directive like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as vmMy">
    <my-directive value="vmMy.foo"></my-directive>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. I used bindToController in other directives with isolated scopes as in this case, but what about my case with scope: true? I read that angular 1.4 allows the use of bindToController with it, but I don´t get how to use it in my case. I was using `scope:true` because I might need to access a few attributes from MyController, and having to pass all of them as attributes to the directive does not seem right.

Comment: Well if you want to use just new scope and outer controller properties then you can of course refer it with `vmMy` which is not flexible at all. On the other hand, you don't have to pass everything with separate attribute.  You can create only one and pass multiple of properties in form of object.

Comment: You can even pass entire outer controller reference so you don't have to have controller-as name in your directive: http://jsfiddle.net/9yhgjk4g/8/

Comment: Yes, but how can I access the property of the outer controller from inside the directive's controller? I tried with `vm.outerObject.foo` in your fiddle but apparently vm.outerObject is undefined

Comment: You are correct, you should use `vm.outerObject.foo` I just forgot `bindToController` in my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9yhgjk4g/10/

Comment: You can access properties of the controller with `scope: true` but in this case you will get tightly coupled to outer controller controller-as identifier, which is not good.

Comment: Could you provide an example on this? I've been trying with no success to make it work, and although I understand what you're saying about not being flexible I would still want to see how to do it. That is, with `scope: true` and accessing foo from outer controller from inside the directive controller (not the directive tamplate).